# Statging Build issue using wildcard provisional profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, archive

There is an iOS provisioning-related issue (not events-related).It looks like test builds can’t be installed on physical iPads. One example is attached.The following errors are printed to the console:

```
Sep 30 11:00:59 my-iPad-3 installd[60] <Error>: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by provisioning profile 'my Mobile'
Sep 30 11:00:59 my-iPad-3 installd[60] <Error>: 0x281000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.r8ROln/foo_extracted/Payload/myiPad.app/myiPad: 0xe8008016
Sep 30 11:00:59 my-iPad-3 installd[60] <Error>: 0x281000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.r8ROln/foo_extracted/Payload/myiPad.app
Sep 30 11:00:59 my-iPad-3 installd[60] <Error>: 0x281000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
```

we are using Xcode build script to build the code.

The same process/code worked last week.

Can any please help me on it what is going wrong here.

Comment: you update your provisioning profile?

Comment: @MirkoCatalano it is a updated provisional profile

Comment: ok so you have update the new provisioning profile in Project > Build Settings

Comment: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by provisioning profile 'my Mobile' look that is like that your user id is not authorizated to used your new provisioning profile, what you update to your provisioning profile? device? user ID? App ID?

Comment: @MirkoCatalano provisional profile has the UDID of my device.

Comment: you have to download as well the  the iOS Developer Certificate and install in your mac, because  your problem is that the name of iOS Developer is not the same that your have install in your mac

Comment: @MirkoCatalano I have checked the certificate in my keychain and the it was matching the requirements. But still when I'm trying to install  into the physical iPads. The installation process is reaching till end and throwing the error " failed to installed" and showing the same error as mentioned